# Unable to connect to Twitter inside app

Tags: android, twitter

I have a splash page that offers social login to users. In the settings activity users can connect to Twitter, if they are logged in with their email address.

I am using the code below to log the user in on the splash page and I am using the same code in the settings activity to log the user in with Twitter if they click on "Connect with Twitter".

My problem is that once I authorize the app to use Twitter, it opens the Splash page instead of the settings activity so it fails to authenticate the user. I am 100% sure that I don't start an intent that should open the splash activity.

After calling `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));`
the Twitter authentication website comes up and when I click Allow the activity should reload, but instead the Splash activity reloads. The splash is the one that opens when I launch the app but can I go around this? (When logging in on the splash page it works fine obviously, the question is why does it open the splash page once it authenticates the user from an inner activity?)

```
private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private AccessToken accessToken;
    User twuser;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.settings_layout);

settings_rl_twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Settings", "Clicked on Connect/Disconnect to Twitter");
                if (isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    new disconnectTwitter().execute();
                 } else {
                     connectTwitter();
                 }

            }
        });

        private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
            return mSharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_TOKEN, null) != null;
        }

        private void connectTwitter() {
            Log.i("Twitter", "connectTwitter()");
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterConst.CONSUMER_KEY);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterConst.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
            twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterConst.CALLBACK_URL);
                        Log.i("Twitter connectTwitter", "Please authorize this app!");
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Twitter connectTwitter", e.getMessage() + "");
                    }
                }
             });
            thread.start();   
        }

        public class Connect_Twitter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {     
                Log.i("tw_userid", result.get(0) + "");
                Log.i("Lekerve name", result.get(1) + "");
                Log.i("photo", result.get(2) + "");


                new twitterSignupAsyncTask().execute(result.get(0), result.get(1), result.get(2), session_userid); 
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                LIST2.clear();
            }

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, params[0]); 
                    Log.i("Settings Twitter OAuth Token1", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken()); 
                    e.putString(TwitterConst.PREF_KEY_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret()); 
                    e.commit();

                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    Log.i("Settings Twitter userID", String.valueOf(userID) + "");
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);

                    Log.i("Settings User userid", String.valueOf(userID) + "");
                    Log.i("Settings User name", user.getName() + ""); 
                    Log.i("Settings User photo", user.getProfileImageURL() + "");
                    String country = "";
                    if (getUserCountry(SettingsActivity.this) != null && !getUserCountry(SettingsActivity.this).equals("")) {
                        Locale loc = new Locale("",getUserCountry(SettingsActivity.this));
                        country = loc.getDisplayCountry();
                    } else {
                        country = "";
                    }

                    Log.i("Settings  User country", country + ""); 
                    twitter_username = user.getName();

                    LIST2.add(String.valueOf(userID));
                    LIST2.add(user.getName());
                    //LIST2.add(user.getScreenName());
                    LIST2.add(user.getProfileImageURL());
                    LIST2.add(country);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  

                return LIST2;
            }
        }


        public class twitterSignupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

                if (result.size() > 0) {

                    //mentsuk el a session_userid-t azert, hogy a kovetkezo app megnyitaskor ismerjuk
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putString(TwitterConst.LASTID, result.get(0));
                    e.commit();

                    Log.i("TWITTER CONNECT RESULT POST", result.get(0));
                } else {
                    Log.i("TWITTER CONNECT RESULT POST", "FAIL");
                }

                settings_connecttw_text.setText("Connected to " + result.get(1));

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() { 
                LIST.clear();
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {

                    Log.i("At tw_id", params[0].toString() + "");
                    Log.i("At name", params[1] + "");
                    Log.i("At photo", params[2] + "");
                    Log.i("At session_userid", params[3] + "");

                    array_user = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    array_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tw_userid", params[0]));
                    array_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[1]));
                    array_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tw_photo", params[2]));
                    array_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", params[3]));

                    JSONParser jsonParser; jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(connect_twitter, "POST", array_user);

                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt("success");
                        Log.d("success", "" + success);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            Log.d("SIGNUP", "success");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("SIGNUP", "fail");
                        }
                        LIST.add(String.valueOf(success));
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    }       
                    LIST.add(params[1]);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return LIST;
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did.

1. Before calling `SettingsActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));` I save the current activity in Sharedpreferences
2. When the splash activity comes up (the main that opens every time I open the app) I check this variable in Sharedpreferences and if it's true then I open up SettingsActivity and send the verifier with the intent.
3. In SettingsActivity now it's easy to log in with this verifier and get user data.

SplashActivity:

```
if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
boolean fromSettingsActivity = mSharedPreferences2.getBoolean(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS, false);
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TwitterConst.CALLBACK_URL)) {
        final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(TwitterConst.IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
        if (fromSettingsActivity) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Splash.this, SettingsActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("verifier", verifier);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
           return;
        } else {    
           new Connect_Twitter().execute(verifier);
        }
    }
}
```

SettingsActivity:

```
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle extras = iin.getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String verifier = extras.getString("verifier");
    new Connect_Twitter().execute(verifier);
}
```

And don't forget to reset the Sharedpreferences value when you click BACK:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mSharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences2.edit();
    e.remove(TwitterConst.FROM_SETTINGS);
    e.commit();
    super.onBackPressed();    
}
```

One more thing

With the current intent the app opens up the SettingsActivity again, so you need to click BACK two times. This is the default behaviour of the Twitter login. To prevent this, use the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```